# Can't reference System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorIno in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing the MS tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?tabs=aspnetcore2x

I'm using VS 2017.

But I want to add a try catch to send errors to the Error.cshtml file in the Shared folder. The tutorial does not do that.

Here's my code. I get the red squiggly line under: HandleErrorInfo.

It states: The type or namespace name 'HandleErrorInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating")] Movie movie)
    {            
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(movie);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Movies", "Create"));
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

So I searched for it in the object browser. It's there.

[image]

But it will not let me bring it in with a using System.Web.Mvc;

It grays out and states: The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Note: Using VS 2015, I do not have any problem referencing it in an MVC5 app that I wrote which references using System.Web.Mvc;

Comment: My be there is a problem with .NET version, when Creating the project in VS

Comment: Not sure as the web app runs fine without the try catch which of course references that HandleErrorInfo.

Comment: Have you got any answer to this problem? I'm in the exact situation now..